# Prove that $\tan x \geq x + \frac{x^3}{3}$ for $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

I am teaching someone basic real analysis. Working through the past exams, they've found the following problem:

Prove that $\tan x \geq x + \dfrac{x^3}{3}$ for $x \in \left[0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

What's the simplest way to prove it? I've found two possible solutions, but both seem too complex for the course level:

1. Use Taylor expansion of the $\tan$ function. While Taylor series were covered in the course, this specific one was not.
2. Plug $x = \arctan y$, and prove that
   $f(y) = y - \arctan y - \dfrac{\arctan^3 y}{3}$
   is monotonically increasing through derivation.
   This works, but it's also fairly tricky.

Is there a simpler solution that I am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For $0 < x < \pi/2 $, prove that $x + \frac{x^{3}}{3} <\tan x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800612/for-0-x-pi-2-prove-that-x-fracx33-tan-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two members are equal when $x=0$. We can differentiate and get

$$\tan^2x+1\ge1+x^2$$ or

$$\tan x\ge x.$$

Again, the two members are equal when $x=0$ and

$$\tan^2x+1\ge1.$$

Below, the functions and their derivatives.

[image]

[image]

Caution: the proof works backwards, starting from $(\tan x)'\ge (x)'\land\tan(0)\ge0$.

Comment: Why does the inequality hold under differentiation? 
In general, if f(x) >= g(x), does it imply f'(x) >= g'(x) ?

Comment: Ah, silly me! I was getting stuck on using $tan'(x) = \frac{1}{cos^2(x)}$ instead of using the alternate form...

Comment: @Mircea: actually, it is the converse. If $h(0)\ge0$ and $h'(x)\ge0$, we have a growing function and $h(x)\ge0$. Consider $h=f-g$.

Answer (score 3):

A simple, if somewhat tedious, solution, using just basic notions of calculus, is to let $f(x)=\tan x-x-{x^3\over3}$ and compute the first three derivatives:

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\sec^2x-1-x^2\\
f''(x)&=2\sec^2x\tan x-2x\\
f'''(x)&=4\sec^2x\tan^2x+2\sec^4x-2
\end{align}$$

We note that $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$ and $f'''(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi/2)$ (since $|\sec x|\ge1$). From $f''(0)=0$ and $f'''(x)\ge0$ it follows that $f''(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi/2)$; from $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(x)\ge0$ it follows that $f'(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi/2)$; finally, from $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)\ge0$ it follows that $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

In my view we can see that $\tan x \geq x$ geometrically in the interval $[0,\pi/2)$
From this we get of course that $\tan^2(x) \geq x^2$ and then $\tan^2(x)+1 \geq x^2+1$. After, **by integration**,  we have
$$
\int\limits_0^x {\left( {\tan ^2 t + 1} \right)} dt \geqslant \int\limits_0^x {\left( {1 + t^2 } \right)} dt
$$
and from this we have the required inequality
[image]

NB: we have the initial required inequality after comparing the areas of the right triangle with the "blue" leg with the area of the circular sector with "red" arc.

Comment: $\tan x>x$ by integration of $\tan^2x+1>1$.

Comment: Yes of course, but at elementary level could be useful also a geometric view.

Comment: Is it worth to mix two methods ? And the figure deserves a minimum of explanation. In particular, there is no visible relation between the lengths of the arc $x$ and the segment $\tan x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's not the length "blue straight segment vs. red arc" but the area  "triangle vs. circular sector". The right triangle with horizontal leg of unity and vertical blue leg of $\tan x$ is visibly larger than the circular sector with span $x$.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin: of course. This is precisely the information missing in the post. I would have preferred the poster to say it. Plus the formula for the area of a sector.

Comment: Of course the relation is between areas and yo are right, I must be more clear. I add a note. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=\tan(x)$ is an odd function fulfilling the differential equation $f'(x)=1+f(x)^2$, hence
$$ f''(x) = 2f'(x)f(x) = 2f(x)(1+f(x)^2), $$
$$ f'''(x) = 2(1+f(x)^2)^2+4 f(x)^2(1+f(x)^2), $$
$$ \ldots $$
and by induction we have that $f^{(2m)}(0)=0$ while $f^{(2m+1)}(0)\in\mathbb{N}^+$. The radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ since $\tan(x)$ is a meromorphic function and $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ are the closest singularities (simple poles) to the origin. In particular, for any $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$ \tan(x) > \sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(0)}{(2k+1)!}\,x^{2k+1} $$
with your inequality being the $N=1$ instance.

Answer (score 1):

let $f(x)=\tan(x)-x-\frac{x^3}{3}$

$f'(x)=\sec^2(x)-1-x^2=\tan^2(x)-x^2\geq 0$, because  $\tan(x)\geq x$ for $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ 
means $f$ is increasing, and so, see that, $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$